# How to use a C function in MATLAB?

Tags: c, matlab

I am trying to use  SLIC Superpixels method written by a group in EPFL.In the demo MATLAB file it is written the following code :

```
img = imread('bee.jpg');
[labels, numlabels] = slicmex(img,500,20);
%numlabels is the same as number of superpixels
imagesc(labels);
```

Indeed in the folder file, there is only this `slicmex.c` file. When I try to run the MATLAB code. There is an error because it does not recognize the `slicmex` function. So in a kind of a way, I should load `slicmex.c` to MATLAB  How can I do it?

Comment: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html

Comment: Looks like you need to make sure that folder is on your PATH.

Comment: As Nicky said, you likely need to compile the C file into a MEX-file. Typically `mex slicmex.c` is enough. Doesn't the toolbox you downloaded have some documentation for how to install it?

Comment: I don't see any meaningful example there . Anyway I want to know did these EPFL guys compile this piece of code? They do not seem to be using any of the mentioned functions there.

Comment: @AustinMullins Indeed at first I thought it was because of that.But I added the files to my path and still it did not work.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you I did as you said. In the command window I typed :
mex slicmex.c  .Now it works. Issue solved.